# login to magento community backend-Invalid Secure BaseURL Store: default Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must contain a dot

Tags: magento-community, wamp

like always windows OS is driving me crazy.I have localhost and I did run n98-magerun sys:check for troubleshoot magento and I know the problem as follows:

```
Invalid Secure BaseURL Store: default Wrong hostname configured. Hostname must
contain a dot
```

through installation when magento asked me to enter the host name I did use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost,
I tried to use www.localhost.com to solve the problem in the hosts file of 
 located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

```
127.0.0.1       www.localhost.com
```

then I went to **httpd.conf**  and I did the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/magento"
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias www.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't change Logs because I didn't need them then in .htaccess of magento I wrote this:

```
 Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
```

- if I enter **localhost/magento/admin** and enter user,pass **I cannot
  login**
- if I enter **www.localhost.com/admin** it will go to admin it will redirect to

  http://localhost/magento/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/blahblah

and I can see the page:

[image]

but if I click on any link again I will be signed out because the domain is localhost and doesn't have dots

I tried to go core_config_data table and search for the base url, I didn't find anything

I tried every solution on the internet, literally everything.

P.S:I just found out that I can login through firefox but not chrome, I know the solution of changing Varien.php but I don't like it and I don't want to change core files it should have a better solution

P.S: As adeel said I increased cookie life time in php.ini from 0 to 3600

```
session.cookie_lifetime = 3600
```

still not working in chrome

Answer (score 1):

Check in below image there you need to set your `base_url` set for both row, Try both `localhost` & `127.0.0.1` , for me both are working fine. Table name is core_cofig_data

If you can't able to find the base url rows, just do a search in core_cofig_data table in path column `web/unsecure/base_url` OR `web/secure/base_url`.

Also increase Cookie Life Time & it will start working fine on Chrome too.

[image]

Comment: as I said I dont have them  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0380 sec)
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE 'web/secure/base_url'

Comment: I also increased cookie life time and restarted apache no result yet